# Reference "this" within member constructor

Tags: java, android, this, android-context

```
public abstract class AndroidTextAdvGame extends Activity implements Game {

Game game;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    game = this;

    rightLinksListener = new View.OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    setScreen( new BookQuestGameScreen(game) );
        }

    };
}
```

Is there anyway I can reference 'this' ( the class I defined )

in the  new `View.OnClickListener` ?

The current workaround is that game member I created, and assigning game=this in the `onCreate` and then using game in the new `View.OnClickListener`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class you defined was called **AndroidTextAdvGame**, then you would refer to its "this" by using

```
AndroidTextAdvGame.this
```

Comment: Thanks man, that did it, now i have to wait 8 minutes to accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes: you can refer to the outer-class instance as `AndroidTextAdvGame.this`. For example:

```
new BookQuestGameScreen(AndroidTextAdvGame.this)
```

(It's a bit strange-looking at first, I admit, but you get used to it.)